# VBA - Merging two scripts

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a problem with combining two scripts into one, I tried to the script, "createTask" to add as text, "msg2" from the "SaveMessageAsMsg" script.

When I tried to merge it either didn't pull msg2 or the createtask script didn't execute properly.

The lower script is to save the selected email on the local network and extract the address to this saved .msg element, and this address is to be used as text in the JsonString of "createTask" script under msg2.

If anyone has an idea how to combine this I would be very grateful.

```
Sub send()
    Dim Sarasa As Object
    Dim x, mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
  
    For Each x In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If TypeName(x) = "MailItem" Then
            Set mailItem = x
            Call createTask(mailItem)
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub

Sub createTask(ByRef mItem As Outlook.mailItem)
    Dim kbUrl As String
    Dim title As String
    Dim kbUsername As String
    Dim kbPassword As String
    Dim kbProjectId As Integer
    Dim kbSwimlaneId As Integer
    kbUrl = "https://website.com/jsonrpc.php"
    kbUsername = "test"
    kbPassword = "test"
    kbProjectId = 1
    kbSwimlaneId = 1

    Set LoginRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    LoginRequest.Option(4) = 13056
    LoginRequest.Open "POST", kbUrl, False
    LoginRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    LoginRequest.SetCredentials kbUsername, kbPassword, 0
    
    title = InputBox(mItem.Subject, "Title")
    If StrPtr(title) = 0 Then
    ElseIf title = vbNullString Then
        JsonString = "{""jsonrpc"": ""2.0"", ""method"": ""createTask"",""id"": 1176509098,""params"": {""score"": 0, ""project_id"": """ & kbProjectId & """, ""swimlane_id"":""" & kbSwimlaneId & """ , ""title"":""" & Format(mItem.CreationTime, "ddd hh:nn") & " / " & Split(mItem.SenderName)(1) & " / " & mItem.Subject & """, ""description"":""" & "[LINK](file:" + msg2 & ")" & """}}"
    Else
        JsonString = "{""jsonrpc"": ""2.0"", ""method"": ""createTask"",""id"": 1176509098,""params"": {""score"": 0, ""project_id"": """ & kbProjectId & """, ""swimlane_id"":""" & kbSwimlaneId & """ , ""title"":""" & Format(mItem.CreationTime, "ddd hh:nn") & " / " & Split(mItem.SenderName)(1) & " / " & title & """, ""description"":""" & "[LINK](file:" + msg2 & ")" & """}}"
    End If
   
    LoginRequest.Send JsonString
    If LoginRequest.Status = 200 Then
        'MsgBox "Mail: " & mItem.Subject & " - Status: " & LoginRequest.responseText
        Call buscaError(LoginRequest.responseText, mItem)
    Else
      MsgBox "The list did not respond - 200 OK"
    End If
End Sub

Function buscaError(strBuscar As String, ByRef mItem As Outlook.mailItem)
    Dim useCategory As String
    useCategory = "LIST"
    Dim olMail As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim RegError As RegExp
    Dim RegExito As RegExp
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match
    Set olMail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)
    Set RegError = New RegExp
    Set RegExito = New RegExp
    
    With RegError
        .Pattern = "(error)"
        .Global = True
    End With
    With RegExito
        .Pattern = "(result)"
        .Global = True
    End With
    
    If RegError.test(strBuscar) Then
        'MsgBox "Mail processing error: " & mItem.Subject
        
    ElseIf RegExito.test(strBuscar) Then
        Call AddCategory(mItem, useCategory)
        'MsgBox "Ok"
    End If
End Function

Sub AddCategory(aMailItem As mailItem, newCategory As String)
    Dim categories() As String
    Dim listSep As String

    listSep = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sList")

    categories = Split(aMailItem.categories, listSep)

    If UBound(Filter(categories, newCategory)) = -1 Then
        ReDim Preserve categories(UBound(categories) + 1)
        categories(UBound(categories)) = newCategory
        aMailItem.categories = Join(categories, listSep)
        aMailItem.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

With this

```
Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg()
      Dim oMail As Outlook.mailItem
      Dim objItem As Object
      Dim sPath As String
      Dim dtDate As Date
      Dim sName As String
      Dim msg2 As String

       For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
       If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
        Set oMail = objItem
       
      sName = oMail.Subject
      ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"
     
      dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
      sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
        vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
        vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"
         
        sPath = "\\local.disk\folder"
        msg2 = sPath & sName
      oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
    
      End If
      Next
      
    End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68415017/edit) the question to put in your attempts. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the functions into two separate ones. In both cases you retrieve the currently selected mail item, so after getting the object you can call two separate functions to get the job done.

```
Sub send()
    Dim Sarasa As Object
    Dim x, mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
  
    For Each x In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If TypeName(x) = "MailItem" Then
            Set mailItem = x
            Call createTask(mailItem)
            Call SaveMessageAsMsg(mailItem)
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub

Sub createTask(ByRef mItem As Outlook.mailItem)
    Dim kbUrl As String
    Dim title As String
    Dim kbUsername As String
    Dim kbPassword As String
    Dim kbProjectId As Integer
    Dim kbSwimlaneId As Integer
    kbUrl = "https://website.com/jsonrpc.php"
    kbUsername = "test"
    kbPassword = "test"
    kbProjectId = 1
    kbSwimlaneId = 1

    Set LoginRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    LoginRequest.Option(4) = 13056
    LoginRequest.Open "POST", kbUrl, False
    LoginRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    LoginRequest.SetCredentials kbUsername, kbPassword, 0
    
    title = InputBox(mItem.Subject, "Title")
    If StrPtr(title) = 0 Then
    ElseIf title = vbNullString Then
        JsonString = "{""jsonrpc"": ""2.0"", ""method"": ""createTask"",""id"": 1176509098,""params"": {""score"": 0, ""project_id"": """ & kbProjectId & """, ""swimlane_id"":""" & kbSwimlaneId & """ , ""title"":""" & Format(mItem.CreationTime, "ddd hh:nn") & " / " & Split(mItem.SenderName)(1) & " / " & mItem.Subject & """, ""description"":""" & "[LINK](file:" + msg2 & ")" & """}}"
    Else
        JsonString = "{""jsonrpc"": ""2.0"", ""method"": ""createTask"",""id"": 1176509098,""params"": {""score"": 0, ""project_id"": """ & kbProjectId & """, ""swimlane_id"":""" & kbSwimlaneId & """ , ""title"":""" & Format(mItem.CreationTime, "ddd hh:nn") & " / " & Split(mItem.SenderName)(1) & " / " & title & """, ""description"":""" & "[LINK](file:" + msg2 & ")" & """}}"
    End If
   
    LoginRequest.Send JsonString
    If LoginRequest.Status = 200 Then
        'MsgBox "Mail: " & mItem.Subject & " - Status: " & LoginRequest.responseText
        Call buscaError(LoginRequest.responseText, mItem)
    Else
      MsgBox "The list did not respond - 200 OK"
    End If
End Sub

Function buscaError(strBuscar As String, ByRef mItem As Outlook.mailItem)
    Dim useCategory As String
    useCategory = "LIST"
    Dim olMail As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim RegError As RegExp
    Dim RegExito As RegExp
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match
    Set olMail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)
    Set RegError = New RegExp
    Set RegExito = New RegExp
    
    With RegError
        .Pattern = "(error)"
        .Global = True
    End With
    With RegExito
        .Pattern = "(result)"
        .Global = True
    End With
    
    If RegError.test(strBuscar) Then
        'MsgBox "Mail processing error: " & mItem.Subject
        
    ElseIf RegExito.test(strBuscar) Then
        Call AddCategory(mItem, useCategory)
        'MsgBox "Ok"
    End If
End Function

Sub AddCategory(aMailItem As mailItem, newCategory As String)
    Dim categories() As String
    Dim listSep As String

    listSep = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sList")

    categories = Split(aMailItem.categories, listSep)

    If UBound(Filter(categories, newCategory)) = -1 Then
        ReDim Preserve categories(UBound(categories) + 1)
        categories(UBound(categories)) = newCategory
        aMailItem.categories = Join(categories, listSep)
        aMailItem.Save
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub SaveMessageAsMsg(ByVal oMail As Outlook.mailItem)
      Dim sPath As String
      Dim dtDate As Date
      Dim sName As String
      Dim msg2 As String
       
      sName = oMail.Subject
      ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "-"
     
      dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
      sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
        vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
        vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"
         
        sPath = "\\local.disk\folder"
        msg2 = sPath & sName
      oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG
    
      End If
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: Strange thing, swap the order of calls to:
Call SaveMessageAsMsg(mailItem)
Call createTask(mailItem)

The msg2 is now generated correctly, but if I use it in json I get pharse error code -32700, if I remove it I get the correct response from the server. I am wondering if this is a json string formatting issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter in which order the methods are called.

Comment: if I leave the order of calls as it was without removing the msg2 value from json string, it gets the correct response from the server but the msg2 field generates as an empty value.

Comment: Is it possible that the "\" characters from the destination \\local.disck\folder\message.msg can cause the sent jsonstring to be misread?